# In Bosch Season 3, what was the villain's original plan? (spoiler)

Tags: plot-explanation, bosch

**Note: it's impossible to even ask the question without spoiling several big events in Season 3.**

That said, you won't be able to help me if you haven't seen the final episode of Season 3, so if that's you, come back later.

---

> Was it always Dobbs' plan to kill his accomplices and keep all the cash for himself?

It appeared that the conspiracy had three core members: Dobbs (the leader), Xavi, and Woody. For most of Season 3, it seemed like they were all genuinely friends (albeit frustrated with Woody's incessant pot use and consequent sloppiness). Once their scheme is complete, each hides his share of the take in a different place (evidently secret from each others).

Then Woody gets killed. Their scheme completed anyway, Dobbs and Xavi agree to get the hell out of Dodge. But Xavi remains in town to avenge Woody's death.

When Dobbs learns about that vengeance from the news, he is obviously (and understandably) upset with Xavi for jeopardizing their chances to get away clean. Xavi anticipates this, as evidenced by the precautions he takes when he finally breaks radio silence to check in with Dobbs. And each lies to the other about his current whereabouts and immediate plans, in a way I read as both defensive and hinting at openness to betrayal.

Then Xavi shows up unexpectedly at Dobbs' boat as he's preparing to go looking for Woody's share. He hides his killing knife aboard, clearly in preparation to kill Dobbs. But Dobbs acts first and kills Xavi.

My initial read is that Xavi was impulsively violent, cocky, and <s>greedy</s> kind of pathologically hungry, and that Dobbs intuited his reason for showing up: with Woody dead, Xavi is just one murder away from keeping all the loot for himself.

But then I remembered that Dobbs put GPS tracking chips into the cases of loot while he was packing them, and I don't recall either Xavi or Woody displaying any awareness of this. I don't think we can say they definitely *didn't* know, just that we never see either of them actually use the tracking chips or talk about them. So, it's possible that Dobbs was tracking the cases so he could hunt his partners down later, when they think the whole ordeal is behind them and their guards are down. Even if we say that Xavi's death was necessary self-defense, Dobbs put those GPS chips in the cases while Woody was still alive.

So: was it always his plan to kill his partners and keep all the money?

Comment: I always assumed that the tracking device meant just that, that he was going to track them down and kill them later, but I agree I'm not certain this was always his plan. S3 is also based on the Bosch books Black Echo & A Darkness More Than Night--Maybe there is some insight to be gleamed there.

Comment: @DarthLocke Can you say: does this conspiracy span both novels, or is it confined to just one?

Comment: I think it is Black Echo's plot, but a lot has been modified, I think, such as it was a character from Bosch's military past. I never read it, but someone who might of, might be able to say just "how" different the plots are, which would then rule in/out how significant it really is to your Q. I just brought it up as a possible direction to go in. Wish I could be more helpful.